# Why is planetary friendship in vedic astrology inconsistent with Hindu mythology?

Tags: gods, astrology, chandra, brihaspati, vedic

According to vedic astrology, Jupiter and Moon are good friends. They conjunction causes the auspicious Gaja Kesari yoga. Jupiter is also exalted in Moon's own sign of Cancer.
However, according to Hindu mythology, Jupiter's (Brihaspati) wife Tara had an affair with Moon (Chandra Dev) resulting in the birth of Budh Dev.
This doesn't make sense logically. Please explain.

Comment: They probably made amends and are now friends again.

Comment: For Astrological purposes, [Moon and Venus are considered as females](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/40744/division-of-navagrahas-based-on-gender) but actually they are male deities. So astrological considerations are a bit different.

Comment: Jupiter is exalted in Cancer as it is the sign of learning, not because it is Moon's mulatrikona. Similarly, Mars is also exalted in Capricorn, but that doesn't imply that Mars and Saturn are friends. It is exalted because Capricorn shows graveyard, and a warrior is the happiest person there.

Comment: Similarly yogas don't signify any planetary friendship/enmity. Sun-Ketu combination is called Shiva Bhakti Yoga, but that doesn't imply that both are friends. And so on.

Comment: Interpolated purnaic stories i.e. smritis should not be used to analyse Apara Vedic knowledge like Vedic Astrology just like Shiva vs Vishnu vs Durga puranic rivalry of Kaliyuga.Anyways, Jupiter represent Brahmins, Guru and pandits, and Moon represents house, mother, nourisher and Jupiter exalts in Cancer(Moon's house, representing night and home & its opposite Capricorn is where Mars exalts, which represents soldier, day and wars).Therefore, Brahmins or Jupiter deals with rituals and house prayers and hence exalts in Pushya(nourisher) constellation of Cancer but debilitates in Capricorn(wars)

Comment: Moon's mooltrikona is Taurus dealing with beauty, creation and ruled by Brahma(Rohini) and Agni(Krittika) and where Moon exalts, not Cancer sign as confused by many.